# How to make a JScrollPane scrollable after a component has been added at runtime

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Unfortunately, I have seen this question multiple times but unfortunately I do not know what I am doing well enough to be able to interpret what I have to implement in my own code.

I have used the GUI editor in netbeans to create a JScrollPane and a JPanel on top of this. I am aware I can create these components at runtime along with everything else but this proved problematic and simply adding the scroll pane and panel in the editor and adding components to them during runtime has worked for me thus far.

So far, creating components and adding them to the panel is no problem. The problem I face is that the scroll pane will not update itself to enable the user to scroll further down to view the created components at the bottom. I have been generating ‘entries’ each time a button is pressed, that currently creates a JTextField and adds this component to the panel, more components are going to be added later but for now this is just experimentation.

Once the ‘list’ of ‘entries’ exceeds the limit of the window, the window has to be resized in order to view components at the bottom but after a certain number of entries (around 25-30) the components are no longer viewable as the scroll bar does not scroll down the panel.

This is how I am adding components at runtime...

```
JTextField txtName1 = new JTextField();

txtName1.setLocation(10, 90);
txtName1.setSize(135, 25);

pnlContainer.add(txtName1);
```

The 'pnlContainer' is attached on top of the 'jspContainer' which is my JScrollPane and I am using the 'repaint()' method to get the components visible on the panel.

So far, adding components at runtime has worked, all of the components are visible and interact-able.

I am fairly new to programming in general with only a few years experience, any documentation that may help, tutorials or anything else is greatly appreciated. Documentation is always welcome as I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: I'd also appreciate comments on how i can improve the way i worded my question, i know its been asked before but i dont understand some of the examples i am looking at and therefore cannot apply the same principles to my code. Additionally, as i am fairly new to this, i dont know what questions i should be asking and how i should be asking them in order to find relative results.

Comment: 1) Take the [tour] and go through the [help], then read [ask] and how to post a valid [mcve] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org). Note that this question is off-topic as it's asking for tutorials / documentation and lacks a MCVE that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: i simply want the scroll pane to enable the user to scroll down the entire program. I dont fully understand how the JScrollPane works, netbeans documentation hasnt really helped much. I have a JScrollPane and a JPanel on that, during execution, when a button is pressed, more components are added to the panel, however when so many components have been produced on the panel, they continue off the bottom of the program window, this is why i wanted a scroll bar as the number of added components will exceed the maximum window height.

Comment: the scroll pane simply doesnt work and im not entirely sure why. the component is there and visible during runtime but as components are produced the scroll bar has not updated to signify the user can scroll down any further nor are you able to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JTextField txtName1 = new JTextField();
txtName1.setLocation(10, 90);
txtName1.setSize(135, 25);
pnlContainer.add(txtName1);
```

> So far, adding components at runtime has worked, all of the components are visible and interact-able.

In you above code example you are setting the size/location of each component which implies you are using a null layout. Don't use a null layout!!!

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers and scrolling will work properly when you use panels with a layout manager.

The layout manager is responsible for determining the "preferred size" of the panel. The panel will then display scrollbars automatically when the preferred size of the panel is greater than the size of the scroll panel.

When you use a null layout the preferred size of the panel is 0, so the scrollbars will never appear.

Comment: Okay, I thought one was set by default, I've just tried a few different layouts but now the scroll bars are no longer appearing. They were before I tried this, I presume I set the layout of the panel rather than the scroll pane, should I use a specific layout?

Comment: @D.mcadam, It sounds like you are adding rows of data. So maybe you should be using a vertical [Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). Or maybe you should be using a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to display your rows of data. We don't have enough information for a specific suggestion.

Comment: If you need more help then post an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So the `MCVE` would simple be a frame with an empty panel and a button to add a component to the panel. You can test this process using the `MCVE` in about 20-30 lines of code. Once you understand the basic concept you apply the knowledge to your real application.

Comment: Okay, I think im going to give it a rest for tonight but it does seem like implementing something incorrectly, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Using a table worked much better, i enabled users to edit data by other means. Thank you